# MYSQL join with Group by - wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom post type in wordpress where I want to get count of posts which are grouped month wise by a custom date field. My output **should be**

```
Month  CountofPost
April  1
August 2
```

My SQL code so far is

```
SELECT monthname(met.meta_value), count(pst.id) AS NumberOfPosts
from  wp_postmeta met 
inner join wp_posts pst 
on met.post_id = pst.ID
where pst.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
and met.meta_key = 'start_date'
and pst.post_status = 'publish'
group by meta_value
```

However, the output of above code is

```
Month  CountofPost
April  1
August 1
August 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your group by clause to `group by monthname(met.meta_value)`

```
select monthname(met.meta_value), count(pst.id) AS NumberOfPosts
from  wp_postmeta met 
inner join wp_posts pst on met.post_id = pst.ID
where pst.post_type = 'custom_post_type'
    and met.meta_key = 'start_date'
    and pst.post_status = 'publish'
group by monthname(met.meta_value)
```